# Deserialize the same JSON field into two different struct fields without implementing Deserialize manually

Tags: rust, serde

My input data looks something like this:

```JSON
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

And the struct I would like to deserialize into looks like this:

```Rust
struct MyStruct {
    key1: String,
    key2: String,
    key2_transformed: String,
}
```

I need the value of `key2` twice, even though it only appears once in the JSON. Additionally, I need to apply a function to the value before storing it in `key2_transformed`.

I cannot turn `key2_transformed` itself into a function that is called when the value is needed, it needs to be a field that stores the result of a function call.

Is this possible without having to implement a custom deserializer?

This is what I tried:

```Rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    key1: String,

    key2: String,

    #[serde(rename = "key2", deserialize_with = "transform_key2")]
    key2_transformed: String,
}
```

Where `transform_key2` is a function that has the signature required for the [`deserialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with) attribute,
but then I get the error `missing field 'key2'`.

I also thought about creating a second struct with the exact same fields as the JSON input to deserialize into. This could then be used to create an instance of `MyStruct`, transforming `key2` once along the way. But compared to that, writing a custom implementation of `Deserialize` for `MyStruct` seems like a better solution.

Comment: So if I am reading this correctly, `key2_transformed` is skipped on serialization and always derived from `key2` on deserialization?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Would you be fine with `key2` being a field that's value is a tuple `(String, String)` (or a custom struct with named fields) for what currently is `key2` and `key2_transformed`, then rewrite `transform_key2 ` to return that tuple/struct and then write a `serialize_with` to just return `key2`?

Comment: *I cannot turn key2_transformed itself into a function that is called when the value is needed, it needs to be a field that stores the result of a function call.* - Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it sounds like you may need to implement deserialize manually. It just is not possible to re-use a deserialized field in that way in most contexts. I imagine there may be some crates which add functionality like you were describing, but I was unable to find any during my initial search. However, you can make things easier on yourself by splitting `key2` out as its own struct. This way you can separate it from the rest of the fields in `MyStruct`.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    key1: String,
    key2: TransformedKey,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TransformedKey {
    initial: String,
    transformed: String,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for TransformedKey {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let initial = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        let transformed = transform_key2(&initial);

        Ok(TransformedKey {
            initial,
            transformed,
        })
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e11e663b4768f4f08ff2b1f70330d1c1)

If you want to keep all of the fields together, you can also create a temporary template struct that you then convert to your main struct.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    key1: String,
    key2: String,
    key2_transformed: String,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyStruct {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        struct MyStructInitial {
            key1: String,
            key2: String,
        }

        let initial = MyStructInitial::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        Ok(MyStruct {
            key1: initial.key1,
            key2_transformed: transform_key2(&initial.key2),
            key2: initial.key2,
        })
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a389fa47fa044138df5d7cd5295aa05b)

Comment: If you're ok with "two-step deserialization", you can do `impl From<MyStructInitial> for MyStruct` and then `MyStruct::from(serde_json::from_str::<MyStructInitial>(input)?)`